# AVPlayer poster frame

Tags: ios, avplayer

When an AVPlayer is at the first frame I would like to show a different frame in the video like a YouTube poster frame.  How would you accomplish something like this?

Comment: I would start by reading the AVAssetImageGenerator docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetImageGenerator_Class/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That works to get the frame.  Would I just display this image in the `contentOverlayView` property of `AVPlayerViewController` or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You would set the contents property of any visible layer accordingly:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:...]; // replace ... with the CGImage returned by AVAssetImageGenerator
view.layer.contents = (__bridge id)image.CGImage;
```

Strangely, you have to create a UIImage, and then convert it back to a CGImage to set the Layer's contents property. You can release the UIImage immediately afterwards with CFRelease or by using the __weak or __autoreleasing designators, or just @autoreleasepool.

Don't let anyone tell you that this is memory-consuming or slow. If you relegate this to a separate thread from the main via NSThread, it's as fast as any other means; and, I've displayed 80 UIImages in this way on one screen before.

But, then again, multi-threading and memory management are my strong-suits, as you can see here:

https://youtu.be/7QlaO7WxjGg